# Filtering Computed Properties

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm working on a list. There you can add and remove elements from it and specify the count of each added element.

I included all Elements to my data
Example:

```
[
  {
    "rowID": "21",
    "rowAnzahl": 1,
    "elementID": "127",
    "elementName": "Element 4"
  },
  {
    "rowID": "22",
    "rowAnzahl": 1,
    "elementID": "109",
    "elementName": "Element 3"
  },
  {
    "rowID": "",
    "rowAnzahl": "",
    "elementID": "106",
    "elementName": "Element 1"
  },
  {
    "rowID": "",
    "rowAnzahl": "",
    "elementID": "112",
    "elementName": "Element 2"
  }
]
```

then i added two computed Properties:

```
elements: function() {
      return this.testData.filter(function(e) {
        return e.rowID
      })
    },
    unusedElements: function() {
      return this.testData.filter(function(e) {
        return !e.rowID
      })
    },
```

then i have these methods:

```
methods: {
    addElement: function(index) {
      var item = this.testData[index];
      item.rowID = 'new' + this.rowCount++;
      item.rowAnzahl = 1;
    },
    removeElement: function(index) {
      var item = this.testData[index];
      item.rowID = '';
      item.rowAnzahl = '';
    }
  },
```

But now my Problem:

The Index begins at 0 for my properties unusedElements and elements… 
But because I need the index number for adding or removing the Element this doesn't work.
Is it possible to filter the method by my elementID? 
Or can I set the elementID as index number?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, I found a solution. 
I changed my methods and connected it to my computed properties and not my data.

```
    methods: {
    addElement: function(index) {
      var item = this.unusedElements[index];
      item.rowID = 'new' + this.rowCount++;
      item.rowAnzahl = 1;
    },
    removeElement: function(index) {
      var item = this.elements[index];
      item.rowID = '';
      item.rowAnzahl = '';
    }
  },
```

Now the simple Index solution works without any problems. 
Sometimes its help just to think a bit different ;D

Answer (score 0):

You can search for the index using findIndex function of the array:

```
var elements = [...]; // Your list
function indexOfElement(elementID) {
    return elements.findIndex((entry) => entry.elementID == elementID);
}
```

Edit: Maybe I didn't understand your question correctly. I will leave this here anyway

Comment: this works, my new method is: 
indexOfElement: function(elementID) {
      var indexNum = this.testData.findIndex((row) => row.elementID == elementID);
      var item = this.testData[indexNum];
      return item.rowID = 'new' + this.rowCount++;
      return item.rowAnzahl = 1;
    }

But it doesn't feel like the best way to do it…